# Bootstrap 3 - Remove padding from container without overflowing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to remove padding from container so I set it's padding-left and padding-right to 0. I have achieved the desired effect but instead I got a strange page overflow effect, as you can see:
[image]

(notice the bottom scrollbar).

So my question is how to get rid of this unwanted effect?

Comment: Can you please provide some relavent HTML/CSS demonstrating this? A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it. The problem was with row's default margins which are 15px on left and right. In order to 'hide' a bottom scrollbar you just need to do:

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```